# Return from background workers

Tags: .net, visual-c++, backgroundworker

I am working on background workers. This is what I need to do: return from a background worker so it returns to the main thread of the program. I am using a windows form application and after canceling the background worker the control should be given back to the form so I can call the same function again.

I have added sample code since the code that I am using inside the while loop is pretty large.

```
void funtion1()    
{
  while(true)
  {
    if(backgroundWorker1->CancellationPending)
    {
       e->Cancel = true;
       return ;
    }
  }
}
```

Note: Currently when I do the same job after stopping the function this returns a `System.NullReferenceException` I have also noted that my DOWORK() event works fine.

What I require is to stop the background worker by `backgroundWorker1->CancelAsync();` and to start the same function again using `backgroundWorker1->RunWorkerAsync();`.

However, when I call the same function with the background worker, the system throws a `System.NullReferenceException`.

Why are `System.NullReferenceException`s being thrown and how can I fix this?

Comment: You can format your code nicely by highlighting it and pushing the {} button

Comment: Control does not have to 'return' to the main thread as that never lost control. Also be (much more) clear about the NullRef exception (what line, stacktrace, details).

Comment: @Henk: still, terminating the task is a good idea, to free up resources for the new request (and fire the `RunWorkerCompleted` event)

Comment: @Ben: That part is there, just badly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

A background thread runs independantly of the thread that started it.  The main thread will continue immediately after starting the other thread.

If you want to do something when the background worker completes, you can handle the WorkerCompleted event.

Also, your code is incorrect.

The code in your DoWork event handler will listen for CancelationPending.  The main thread calls Cancel on the BW which sets CancelationPending.

You should read up on the BW here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx

Comment: I cant understand how the RunWorkerCompleted event works after calling the   backgroundWorker1->CancelAsync() method.Aslo in all the examples I found they just print something on the console or in a label but I dont understand how this will return to the main thread.